# Trying to maintain DRY in a C# BLL

Tags: c#, dry

I am working inside a public BLL with a number of different static methods. Inside a few of these methods, I need to display a certain string to the user depending on an ID# passed into the method. The situation is identical across these few methods. It's currently like this:

```
public class myBLL
{
    public static addByID(int ID)
    {
        string myString = grabString(ID);
        //do some stuff
        Console.Writeline("You have added: " + myString);
    }

    public static removeByID(int ID)
    {
        string myString = grabString(ID);
        //do some other stuff
        Console.WriteLine("You have removed: " + myString);
    }

    public static grabString(int ID)
    {
        if(ID == 1)
            return "string 1";
        else
            return "string 2";
     }
}
```

I feel like I am violating DRY in myMethod1 and myMethod2 because why bother calling grabString twice? However I cannot come up with a way around this.

Comment: remove method 2. It's redundant.

Comment: Well this is simplified. myMethod1 and myMethod2 do a lot more than what I have posted. Removing one isn't really an option.

Comment: For your particular code, there is no need of `myMethod2`, I guess you have more complex case and IMO your current code doesn't explain that situation.

Comment: Are myMethod1 and myMethod2 rlevant for the business use case and they are just hapenning to be implemented the same for now? The business smeantics matter, implementation can be refactored

Comment: @Habib, correct: see edit

Comment: @mattm, how you are calling `grabString` twice, you are calling it once in each method, are `method1` and `method2` called together ?

Comment: I have a sneaking suspicion that there are multiple other design issues at play here.  In the specific example, the only recommendation I'd make it to make the helper method `private` since it's only used within that class.  But I imagine these BLL methods may more rightly belong in a more object-oriented structure.  To address your specific question, *calling a method* isn't business logic, so repeating that call isn't necessarily violating DRY.

Comment: @David, very valid point. There's more than 2 methods at play in actuality, and I just felt like I was doing something wrong by copying and pasting `string myString = grabString(ID);` so many times.

Comment: This has nothing to do with DRY, don't overthink it.

Comment: @mattm: There are a number of ways to make that more natural, including perhaps adding an extension method if "grab string" is indeed part of the domain specific language being employed in business processed or if it's perhaps a very commonly performed activity, but I don't suspect that's the case here.  There's nothing inherently wrong with calling a method many times, that's not really repeating code.  (Consider another example, how often do you write `foreach (var value in collection)`?  Would you want to try to eliminate that?  Probably not.)

Comment: The fact that "with a number of different static methods" is likely more significant issues with (potentially imagined) issues with DRY violations (methods like `removeById` feel belonging to some repository and should not be static).

Comment: @Alexei, while you may be right, just keep in mind what I posted is an extremely simplified example, and making the changes you suggest are way beyond the scope of what I'm currently attempting to do.

Comment: Side note: consider reading "Working Effectively with Legacy Code" book... it may help you to not break things on the way.

Comment: Eerie...I actually placed an order for that on amazon two nights ago! Thank you though, lol.

Comment: I know I'm a bit late to this conversation, but I would highly advise against having a static BLL/DAL (especially those that modify data, and especially without some kind of `lock`). While it's true that a relational database will manage any calls that come in simultaneously without conflict in most cases, there's no guarantee that your application will. Ex: Imagine if you had a call for `grabString(1)` and `removeByID(1)` hit your stack at the same time. If your application processes `removeByID` first, then what happens to `grabString`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hard to evaluate what you really are looking for. But might I suggest some sort of logger? Or maybe a general class that store the value for later use?

```
public class myBLL
{
    public static addByID(int ID)
    {
        //do some stuff
        LogString("You have added: {0}", ID);
    }

    public static removeByID(int ID)
    {
        //do some other stuff
        LogString("You have removed: {0}", ID);
    }

    public static LogString(string message, int ID)
    {
        string myString = "";

        if(ID == 1)
            myString = "string 1";
        else
            myString = "string 2";

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(message, myString);
     }
}
```

To be honest, I would remove those static function and create a proper class.

```
public class MyObject
{
    int ID;

    public GetString()
    {
        if(ID == 1)
            return "string 1";
        else
            return "string 2";
     }

}
```

That way, the string could even be cached.

Answer (score 2):

What about to use delegate for different parts of methods

```
public static void myGeneralMethod(int ID, Action<string> method )
{
    string myString = grabString(ID);
    method(myString);
    Console.WriteLine(myString);
}

public static void SomeStuffForAdd(string myString)
{

}
public static void SomeOtherStuffRemove(string myString)
{

}
```

Or if you want to keep Add/Remove:

```
public static void removeByID(int ID)
{
   myGeneralMethod(ID, SomeStuff);
}
```

Comment: +1 Refactoring shared portion in delegate is probably only remaining thing to do here if one wants to stick with static methods instead of reasonable classes. Note that original code is probably more readable - be careful before applying this.

Comment: Yes, although I see that this solves the issue, it will be too much of a break with the convention (there are lots of BLLs, all simply composed of static methods...I wouldn't want to have a random delegate in one of them). However, thank you!

Comment: I've added change how to keep existing methods (helpers should be made private in this case).

Comment: This feels like a big stretch from the original example. In this case we have 1 method being called via an abstraction that implies *multiple* methods could be called.   I'd caution against using delegates in ways that only serve to obfuscate the original design.

Comment: @P.Brian - Can you post an alternative?

Comment: @mattm - No, IMO the example is either oversimplified and not a good representation of the problem you are facing or the code does not require a change.  A method is by definition a piece of re-useable code.  Calling said method from multiple places is normal.

Comment: And that's why i just answer the question how to remove DRY violating

Comment: @mattm, i think  P.Brian.Mackey is right in that our trying to remove DRY violation could'n violate something else like for example One Response principle. And Method must do something general and complitly but not only part of some responce. And final answer realy depends of what original method contains.